# RestResponse does not return expected statuc code in Apex Rest unit test

Tags: unit-test, apexrest

Apex Rest returns 200 OK status code when directly access its Rest endpoint. However, in Apex Rest test class. RestResponse hooked in RestContext does not contains the status code (see below debug log).

Here is my test method. The containing class is also annotated with @isTest

```
@isTest
static void testCreateUser() {
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    TestUtil.initTestData();

    User customerAdmin = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM User WHERE username = 'testuser@acorp.com'];

    String requestBody = '{ "firstName": "Test", "lastName": "Case 2", "email": "testuser2@acorp.com" }';

    req.requestURI = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() + '/services/apexrest/MyId';
    req.httpMethod = 'POST';
    req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(requestBody);

    Test.startTest();
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response = res;

    System.runAs(customerAdmin) {
        UserManagementRestController.createMyId();

        System.debug(req);
        System.debug(res);
    }

    Test.stopTest();
    // Something goes wrong here. No content in RestContext.response
    // Tempoary disable assertion on response
    //System.assertEquals(200, res.statusCode);

    List<User> users = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Username, AccountId FROM User WHERE Email = 'testuser2@acorp.com'];
    System.assertEquals(1, users.size());

    User u = users[0];
    System.assertEquals('Test', u.FirstName);
    System.assertEquals('Case 2', u.LastName);
    System.assertEquals('testuser2@acorp.com', u.Username);
    System.assertEquals(customerAdmin.AccountId, u.AccountId);
}
```

My Apex REST class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyId/*')
global class UserManagementRestController {

    @HttpPost
    global static void createMyId() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        User requestUser = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

        // check if reqest user is customer admin
        Set<String> userPermissions = new Set<String>(UserPermissionRemoter.getUserPermission(requestUser.Id));
        if(!userPermissions.contains(UserPermissionMapper.customerAdminPermissionName)) {
            responseBadRequest('Only Customer Admin can perform this action', res);
            return;
        }

        MyId hid;
        try {
            hid = (MyId)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(), MyId.class);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            responseBadRequest(e.getMessage(), res);
            return;
        }
        System.debug('hid:');
        System.debug(hid);

        String email = hid.email;

        if(!isValidateEmail(email)) {
            responseBadRequest('Invalidate Email', res);
            return;
        }

        // check if new email is in the same domain with super user
        String[] splitEmail = email.split('@');
        String[] splitCurrentUserEmail = requestUser.Email.split('@');
        if(splitEmail[1].compareTo(splitCurrentUserEmail[1]) != 0) {
            responseBadRequest('Email domain mismatched. The new user email must have the same domain as the customer admin’s email.', res);
            return;
        }

        Savepoint createNewUserSavePoint = Database.setSavepoint();
        try {
            Contact newCt = new Contact();
            newCt.FirstName = hid.firstName;
            newCt.LastName = hid.lastName;
            newCt.Email = hid.email;
            newCt.AccountId = requestUser.AccountId;
            insert newCt;

            // Directly use corporate email
            String username = newCt.Email;

            // gen nickname
            DateTime currentTime = System.now();
            Long timeInMili = currentTime.getTime()/1000;
            String nickname = splitEmail[0]+timeInMili;

            // gen alias
            String alias = username;
            if(alias.length() > 8) {
                alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
            }

            User newUsr = new User();
            newUsr.FirstName = newCt.firstName;
            newUsr.LastName = newCt.lastName;
            newUsr.Email = newCt.email;
            newUsr.CommunityNickname = nickname;
            newUsr.profileId = getCommunityProfileId();
            newUsr.contactId = newCt.Id;
            newUsr.UserName = username;
            newUsr.Alias = alias;
            newUsr.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            newUsr.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
            newUsr.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
            newUsr.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
            newUsr.IsActive = true;

            insert newUsr;
        } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
            Database.rollback(createNewUserSavePoint);
            if(String.valueOf(e).contains('DUPLICATE_USERNAME')||String.valueOf(e).contains('DUPLICATE')){
                responseBadRequest('An account with this email already exists', res);
                return;
            }
            else{
                responseBadRequest(String.valueOf(e), res);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Boolean isValidateEmail(String email) {
        //Pattern p = Pattern.compile('^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$');
        //Matcher m = p.matcher(email);

        // according to SFDC support: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170904&language=en_US
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile('^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&\'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');
        Matcher m = p.matcher(email.toUpperCase());
        return m.matches();
    }

    private static Id getCommunityProfileId() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'My Customer Portal User' limit 1][0];
        return p.Id;
    }

    private static void responseBadRequest(String message, RestResponse res) {
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(message);
        res.statusCode = 400;
        return;
    }

    public class MyId {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String email;

        public Boolean isCustomerAdmin;
        public Boolean isActive;
    }
}
```

In the debug log we can see the RestRequest is correctly set. However the RestResponse does not have any value in it. Would expect `statusCode=200`

```
21:56:59.902 (25902510196)|USER_DEBUG|[30]|DEBUG|RestRequest:[headers={}, httpMethod=POST, params={}, remoteAddress=null, requestBody=Blob[77], requestURI=Url:[delegate=http://cs1.salesforce.com]/services/apexrest/MyId, resourcePath=null]
21:56:59.902 (25902571034)|USER_DEBUG|[31]|DEBUG|RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]
```

So what is the reason of getting different result from the test class and the actual Rest endpoint? Any way to test the exact behaviour of Apex Rest endpoint in a unit test class?

Comment: Have you read this? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/writing-test-classes-for-apex-restservice

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes I have read it before asking this question. Is that really related to my question? My problem is to test the endpoint with different user. I can't see the post is helping me in this way.

Comment: And I am wondering why my question is -1 now. Can someone point out the problem and let me to improve my question asking skill next time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You can definitely test with runAs(); 2) The -1 is probably because you didn't include the essence of your post-annotated method

Comment: @crop1645 Actually I use runAs() in many other test cases for a long time and they work well. However this is the first time for me to use it to test in Apex REST classes. And I don't think it works well.

Comment: @OscarTang - Your login in the rest resource is not present. I would say there is something in your logic causing the issue. Until that is available there is no way we can tell if it is a bug or an issue with your code.

Comment: @Eric How can I "Login" in an Apex REST test? Is there any reference?
I have tried the apex rest endpoint without authorization header, it returns INVALID_SESSION_ID error code instead of nothing. Is there some way to add authorization message to the request in a test?

Comment: Any further information I can provide to help you to trace the cause? Thanks in advance

Comment: @OscarTang - Sorry, autocorrect - Logic not login

Comment: @Eric - no login is required to test REST-annotated methods; the test is done as if the login already happened

Comment: @crop1645 - See above comment. It was supposed to be Logic not login. OP did not include the Rest logic in his code that was posted

Comment: @Eric -- this is not my day ...apologies

Comment: @crop1645 - Haha, I know the feeling, believe me!

Comment: haha i see. I have updated the code block =]
Actually it is working with my manual test using other rest client. It has correct status code return so I think there isn't much logically problem in my code.

Comment: And also those five assertions are passed. The Apex rest has done their job well.

Comment: Oscar, it may help if you update the question to better explain your exact question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Done. btw is that really duplicated with http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/writing-test-classes-for-apex-restservice ? That question is suggesting to setup the RestContext **in the test class** before calling the Apex Rest class. Here is talking about setup the RestContext **in the apex rest class** for proper assertion of the RestResponse in test class right?

Comment: I only replied because I saw a lot of comments, usually that indicates that the question is not clear. When answering something in comments, it's good to also update the question so that other users can get the full info instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @Eric I finally figure out the problem. It is not related to System.runAs(). runAs() works well in the test case.

Root cause: The response from `RestContext.reponse` in Test Class is different from what we are getting through the Apex REST endpoint.

For example:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyRest/*')
global class MyRestController {
    @HttpGet
    global static String myRest() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        return 'From myRest';
    }
}
```

You will get

**In Apex Test:**

`RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]`

**When calling the Apex REST endpoint with REST client:**

`Status: 200 OK Body: "From myRest"`

Salesforce Apex REST helps you to return status 200 and set the response body to the return String of myRest(). However this behaviour does not reflect in `RestContext.response` of Apex Rest test case. You have to explicitly set it in the code if you want to test the response...

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyRest/*')
global class MyRestController {
    @HttpGet
    global static String myRest() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        // set the status code and response body for test case
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('From myRest');

        return 'From myRest';
    }
}
```

You will get

**In Apex Test:**

```
RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=Blob[11], statusCode=200]
RestResponse.responseBody.toString():From myRest
```

Answer (score 0):

You are debugging properties that have never been assigned or set

And you test should be

```
res = UserManagementRestController.createMyId();
```

And your debugs should be:

```
System.debug(req);
System.debug(res);
```

or simply system.debug(UserManagementRestController.createMyId());

BUT, your post could return something like a string. Try changing void to string and simply return 'test' and see what you get.

There is no response as there is NO REST communication going on. If you want to test the response, all you can do is use test.setMock and implement the appropriate interface. You can also test from the dev console by actually constructing the http, send the request, and evaluate the response

Comment: I think it is normal to return nothing? From the official guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm , I see there is an example to declare the return type as void.

Comment: Anyway I have tried your suggest:  `global static RestResponse createMyId() {`
But it pumps the following error during compile: `Invalid type for Http* method: System.RestResponse`

Comment: @OscarTang - Ok, maybe you can leave it void, **BUT** read the last part of my answer. You are debugging the RestContext.Response which is null because nothing has been assigned to it, res is null because nothing has been assigned to it. At the very least leave it void and debug UserManagementRestController.createMyId(); see updated answer.

Comment: For `System.debug(UserManagementRestController.createMyId());`
it throws: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: System.debug(void)`

For `res = UserManagementRestController.createMyId();`, it throws: `Illegal assignment from void to RestResponse`

Comment: @OscarTang - hence why you need to return something. You are confusing issues with your debug vs the return. You initial code is simply always going to debug null regardless of what you do because it is coded wrong.

Comment: OK I have tried to return a String in my method, then use a debug statement to catch it in the test class. Yes, the debug message show the returned String. However the rest response is still show null fields.... `res: RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]`

Comment: I need to integrate the Apex REST endpoint with other service so checking the RestResponse is very important to me in the test case. Also we have our requirement to response only 200 status code with no body. Returning a String is not part of our consideration.

Comment: There is no response as there is NO REST communication going on. If you want to test the response, all you can do is use test.setMock and implement the appropriate interface. You can also test from the dev console by actually constructing the http, send the request, and evaluate the response

Comment: hmmm i see. That means I should fall back to the old way (before v24) to test? Like the one mentioned [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/03/21/writing-unit-tests-for-v24-apex-rest-services/)?

Comment: @OscarTang - I see NO point in that at all. Test your method. Salesforce will return the HTTPResponse Headers with the body as your return value. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm. All you need to do is ensure that the methods returns the correct value. If you want to make sure the rest resource works (can be called), call it from the dev console. You are making unnecessary work for yourself

Comment: Then thats go back to my question... Why I can't get expected RestResponse in my test case?...

Comment: I am quite sure that the Apex REST endpoint is working as expected outside the test case. I have tried it manually with other REST client. But now I can't test it with automated Salesforce unit test....

Comment: @OscarTang - Because the response is generated as part of a web request. You are not making a callout to the rest resource (cannot callout during test methods) you are invoking the method directly just like any other method and it is NOT being invoked as a web request

Comment: @OscarTang - `if it needs any context (via its own references to RestContext) you will still need the RestContext setup before you call the methods`

Comment: So what you mean is, we can't test the response from unit test? Then I don't think so. When I try to comment out System.runAs, the RestResponse returns the correct behaviour.

Comment: This is what I got from the log after commenting out System.runAs statement: `20:05:16.446 (30446414102)|USER_DEBUG|[35]|DEBUG|testCreateUser req: RestRequest:[headers={}, httpMethod=POST, params={}, remoteAddress=null, requestBody=Blob[77], requestURI=Url:[delegate=http://cs1.salesforce.com]/services/apexrest/MyId, resourcePath=null]
20:05:16.446 (30446511157)|USER_DEBUG|[36]|DEBUG|testCreateUser res: RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=Blob[43], statusCode=400]`

Comment: Then what if you put the RestRequest and RestResponse inside of the run as?

Comment: I finally understand what you mean for "returning something from the rest class". And I have put a new answer for my findings. Thanks for your patience in answering my question.